# Ist "befüllen" eine sprachliche Neuschöpfung aus dem Umfeld der Datenverarbeitung?

Tags: synonym

Im Zusammenhang mit Datenbanken hört man oft das Tabellenspalten "befüllt" werden.

Irgendwie klingt diese Wortschöpfung, die durch Hinzufügen einer Vorsilbe entstanden ist, schlichtweg überflüssig, da sie eigentlich nichts über den Sachverhalt, sondern etwas über das Umfeld des Sprechers aussagen.

Im Umfeld der Datenverarbeitung ist diese Tendenz vorhandene Worte mit Vorsilben zu versehen weit verbreitet. Man denke an

> ausdrucken - drucken
>   abspeichern - speichern
>   editieren - edieren
>   etc.

Ich vermute alle diese Formen sind nach 1950 entstanden. Sind diese Tendenzen vorhandene Wörter zu modifizieren auch in anderen Bereichen vorhanden?

Comment: Sehr schön! Außerdem hängen wir gerne hinten noch dran, was schon da ist, wie bei LCD-Diplay. Andererseits nicht EDV: `abstrafen`, wo ein `strafen` reichen würde.

Comment: `strafen-bestrafen`, `lehren-belehren`, `abgreifen-begreifen`! Manchmal sind Bedeutungsunterschiede durch ein Präfix subtil, manchmal drastisch, nie sinnlos - sonst gäbe es sie nicht.

Comment: Ich habe noch nie das Wort "edieren" gesehen, geschweige denn verwendet.

Comment: edieren: herausgeben, veröffentlichen; editieren: bearbeiten, nachbessern; Das sind doch verschiedene Bedeutungen…

Comment: @feeela: Zumal hier keine Vorsilbe hinzugefügt, sondern eine Silbe in der Mitte eingefügt wurde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dass im Deutschen (und anderen Sprachen auch?) die Tendenz besteht, die Sprache zu verkomplizieren, ist nichts sehr Neues. Siehe: Problem-Problematik, ändern-abändern, …

Vielleicht erkennt der ein oder andere leichte Bedeutungsunterschiede bei den genannten Wörtern (ich sehe da keine).

Der Fall "editieren" ist jedoch auch anders erklärbar: Hier glaube ich, dass eine Anlehnung an das englische Wort "edit" zum Sieg über "edieren" geführt hat. Vielleicht gilt Ähnliches auch für das Wort "ausdrucken"?

Comment: Yes, to outprint sth. :)

Comment: Mir sind auch schon doppelte Vorsilben untergekommen, aber sie fallen mir leider momentan nicht ein. Sowas wie 'aufbe~', 'anver~' aber nicht 'aufbewahren' oder 'anverwandeln', sondern richtig schief-schrilles.

Comment: Jetzt ist es mir eingefallen: `Abverkauf`. Ist das mehr als ein Verkauf?

Comment: Der Abverkauf ist ein Verkauf von Resten, wo die letzten Lagerbestände eines Produkts abgebaut, also abverkauft werden.

Comment: Lagerbestände werden aber auch abgebaut, wenn es nicht die letzten Reste sind - also so erklärt sich das Wort für mich nicht.

Answer (score 6):

Mit [*"befüllen"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/befuellen) wird das Füllen eines irgendwie gearteten Behälters beschrieben.

> Den Tintenbehälter mit Tinte befüllen

So kann man auch ein Datenfeld einer Tabellenkalulation als einen "Behälter" verstehen, der dann mit Daten befüllt wird.

Es handelt sich keinesfalls um eine Neuschöpfung, da dieses Wort bereits lange vor der Erfindung des Personal Computers verwendet wurde.

Comment: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=bef%C3%BCllen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3

Comment: und http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=gef%C3%BCllt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3 Ich habe früher Tintenbehälter mit Tinte **gefüllt**.

Comment: @Takkat Also meine Großmutter befüllt schon immer die Gläser bei einwecken…